# Mongodb Query on a field of a last document in a nested Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I come from SQL world, and still learning to query MongoDB, and I faced this problem...

## Setup:

I have a Student collection which has an array of Meetings

```
student: {
  meetings: [
    {time: x},
    {time: y},
    {time: z}
  ]
}
```

meetings array has a dynamic size, and its elements are sorted by time in asc, so the first meeting in the array would have the earliest time.

I am able to query to get all students whose first meeting begins after certain time by:

```
db.students.find( { "meetings.0.time": {$gt: ISODate()} } )
```

## Question:

Now I also need to query to get all students whose LAST meeting begins before certain time. However, the following didn't work:

```
db.students.find( { "meetings.-1.time": {$lt: ISODate()} } )
```

How would you guys solve this problem?

Comment: Can't answer properly from phone. Buy you will be able to do this using the aggregation framework. Have a look on mongodb docs.

Comment: If the last time is less than the date then all the times in the array would be less than that date.  maybe meets.forEach.time would work?

Comment: "LAST" by position in the array or "LAST" as in "latest"?

Comment: @sambomartin Great! Good to hear that this is possible. I'll check out the framework.

Comment: @Four_lo That is an interesting point! But, if I understand correctly, you're now iterating the list, when you should be able to just look at one element. I might use this solution if I can limit the number of meetings to a very small number, but still feels very hacky. Even so, it is a quite clever idea. Thank you!

Comment: @NukNukSan "LAST" by position. In my example, because the array is sorted in asc order, last-by-position is "latest" as well. But my question is to get the last-by-position.

Comment: You could use aggregate command. $unwind the array and then $group to get the meeting for the max time per student. You could either $limit before Or after the group depending on what you want to return

Comment: @sambomartin Thanks, I'll try that and once I figure it out, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
db.student.aggregate(
  { $unwind : "$meetings" },
  { $group : { _id: "$_id", lastMeeting : { $max : "$meetings.time" }}},
  { $match: { lastMeeting : { $lt : IsoDate(...) } } 
);
```

Comment: How would you change this to actually select the last element in the array, instead of using $max?

Comment: that's not possible (yet) using the aggregation framework. There are a few jira tickets relating to this https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4589 and i think this would be useful https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6074. Alternative methods I've seen would be to hold a sequence / order as an attribute in each element (meeting) - there are examples of creating a sequence on mongodb examples. If you're happy to do some processing in app you could use $slice http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/slice/. Another technique would be to hold a "lastMeeting" copy next to the array

Comment: You could also use an ObjectId for each meeting too - this is unique and sequential**